# Como extraer las clases encontradas en una captura en tiempo real de object detction con la APi de tensorflow?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

Buen dìa, lo que quiero lograr es extraer en tiempo real las etiquetas de los objetos detectados en la videocamara para poder almacenarlos en un txt o xml o json.

Alguien tiene una idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Estoy usando python 3.6 con la API de Tensorflow 1.8 y open cv para captura de video en tiempo real

SALUDOS

Comment: Me parece muy interesante, me uno a la petición!

Answer (score 0):

Para un caso simple de imágenes podrías utilizar directamente el modelo de [Object Detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) sobre TensorFlow.

Este ejemplo hace la detección sobre una imagen. La función actual trabaja con los *boxes* y las *classes*, además la recomendación es utilizar el *score* de la detección para tener una mejor experiencia en el resultado.

El modelo utilizado en la implementación es *ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17* luego podrías utilizar uno mas ágil si es que quieres mas velocidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el caso de videos o el stream de la cam, bueno aquí si CV es útil, te dejé la modificación del ejemplo con un video, simulando el stream de la cam.*aquí hay que trabajar el paralelismo para algo de producción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto completo está en [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zAmmvXGKIsBlZnWW1ZqHvP1EuKo3h1ZA), prontamente lo voy a incluir GitHub para mantenerlo mejor.